# oracle - add RAW to RAW (or BINARY to BINARY)

Tags: oracle, binary, addition

Three different functions return the same data type according to dump()

```
select 
 dump(utl_raw.cast_to_raw('j')), 
 dump(utl_raw.cast_from_number(1)), 
 dump(utl_raw.cast_from_binary_integer(1)) 
from dual;

DUMP(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW('J'))
-----------------------------------------------------
DUMP(UTL_RAW.CAST_FROM_NUMBER(1))
-----------------------------------------------------
DUMP(UTL_RAW.CAST_FROM_BINARY_INTEGER(1))
-----------------------------------------------------
Typ=23 Len=1: 106
Typ=23 Len=2: 193,2
Typ=23 Len=4: 0,0,0,1
```

...however non of them can be added together.

```
select 
 utl_raw.cast_to_raw('j') + 
 utl_raw.cast_from_number(1), 
 utl_raw.cast_from_number(1) +
 utl_raw.cast_from_binary_integer(1),
 utl_raw.cast_from_binary_integer(1) + 
 utl_raw.cast_to_raw('j')
from dual;

ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got BINARY
```

How can I perform arithmetic on RAW, in particular - add RAW/BINARY to RAW/BINARY?

Edit: This question arose from a need to **iterate through alphabet**. I spotted that it's not so obvious how to add 1 to ascii code and then return with greater letter, eg. 'a' + 1 = 'b'

Comment: What would you expect to be the result of adding together multiple `RAW` values?  What would you do with the result if you got one?

Comment: In answer to Your questions I edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to add together binary values.  If you just want to iterate through the alphabet, just use the `ASCII` and `CHR` functions.  For example

```
select ascii('a') ascii_code,
       ascii('a') + 1 next_ascii_code,
       chr( ascii('a') + 1 ) next_char
  from dual
```

will show you the ASCII code of a lower case a (which will be 97 assuming your database character set is a superset of US7ASCII), the ASCII code of the next character (98), and the next character in character set (a lower case b).  If you want to iterate through the alphabet in a loop

```
FOR i IN 1 .. 26
LOOP
  dbms_output.put_line( chr( ascii('a') + i - 1 ) );
END LOOP;
```

Comment: Justin, thanks for answer, but I will accept an answer if some one will show how to add RAW and BINARY data types. If the data type is the same, then how come I cannot add them? Maybe "+" operator expects NUMBERs ?

Comment: @JakubPietkun - What would it mean to you to add two `raw` values?  How would that be useful?  The addition operator is really only meaningful for numeric data types.

Comment: I understand, I think it's just about I'm just stubborn and want to show that there is a data type that cannot be summed together. I think it's the matter of "plus" operator. It expects numeric values, that's the reason for error "expected NUMBER got BINARY". Accepting the answer.

Comment: @JakubPietkun - There are many data types that cannot be summed together.  It makes no sense to add two movies, for example.  It makes no sense to add two bits of encrypted text.  It makes no sense to add two strings.  It makes no sense to add binary representations of numbers particularly when you've got different binary representations of the same numeric value.